# qqnorm and qqline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

Say have a linear model LM that I want a qq plot of the residuals. Normally I would use the R base graphics:

```
qqnorm(residuals(LM), ylab="Residuals")
qqline(residuals(LM))
```

I can figure out how to get the qqnorm part of the plot, but I can't seem to manage the qqline:

```
ggplot(LM, aes(sample=.resid)) +
    stat_qq()
```

I suspect I'm missing something pretty basic, but it seems like there ought to be an easy way of doing this.

**EDIT:** Many thanks for the solution below. I've modified the code (very slightly) to extract the information from the linear model so that the plot works like the convenience plot in the R base graphics package.

```
ggQQ <- function(LM) # argument: a linear model
{
    y <- quantile(LM$resid[!is.na(LM$resid)], c(0.25, 0.75))
    x <- qnorm(c(0.25, 0.75))
    slope <- diff(y)/diff(x)
    int <- y[1L] - slope * x[1L]
    p <- ggplot(LM, aes(sample=.resid)) +
        stat_qq(alpha = 0.5) +
        geom_abline(slope = slope, intercept = int, color="blue")

    return(p)
}
```

Comment: Note: for residuals, ggplot needs **standardized** residuals. See jlhoward's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19990107/3163618

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The following code will give you the plot you want.  The ggplot package doesn't seem to contain code for calculating the parameters of the qqline, so I don't know if it's possible to achieve such a plot in a (comprehensible) one-liner.

```
qqplot.data <- function (vec) # argument: vector of numbers
{
  # following four lines from base R's qqline()
  y <- quantile(vec[!is.na(vec)], c(0.25, 0.75))
  x <- qnorm(c(0.25, 0.75))
  slope <- diff(y)/diff(x)
  int <- y[1L] - slope * x[1L]

  d <- data.frame(resids = vec)

  ggplot(d, aes(sample = resids)) + stat_qq() + geom_abline(slope = slope, intercept = int)

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I took the liberty of slightly modifying the code to extract the vector directly from a linear model. Of course your solution will work with data that isn't in the form of a linear model, but I thought someone else might want a convenience function for building a qqplot from a LM.

Answer (score 24):

You can also add confidence Intervals/confidence bands with this function (Parts of the code copied from `car:::qqPlot`)

```
gg_qq <- function(x, distribution = "norm", ..., line.estimate = NULL, conf = 0.95,
                  labels = names(x)){
  q.function <- eval(parse(text = paste0("q", distribution)))
  d.function <- eval(parse(text = paste0("d", distribution)))
  x <- na.omit(x)
  ord <- order(x)
  n <- length(x)
  P <- ppoints(length(x))
  df <- data.frame(ord.x = x[ord], z = q.function(P, ...))

  if(is.null(line.estimate)){
    Q.x <- quantile(df$ord.x, c(0.25, 0.75))
    Q.z <- q.function(c(0.25, 0.75), ...)
    b <- diff(Q.x)/diff(Q.z)
    coef <- c(Q.x[1] - b * Q.z[1], b)
  } else {
    coef <- coef(line.estimate(ord.x ~ z))
  }

  zz <- qnorm(1 - (1 - conf)/2)
  SE <- (coef[2]/d.function(df$z)) * sqrt(P * (1 - P)/n)
  fit.value <- coef[1] + coef[2] * df$z
  df$upper <- fit.value + zz * SE
  df$lower <- fit.value - zz * SE

  if(!is.null(labels)){ 
    df$label <- ifelse(df$ord.x > df$upper | df$ord.x < df$lower, labels[ord],"")
    }

  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=z, y=ord.x)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_abline(intercept = coef[1], slope = coef[2]) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha=0.2) 
  if(!is.null(labels)) p <- p + geom_text( aes(label = label))
  print(p)
  coef
}
```

**Example:**

```
Animals2 <- data(Animals2, package = "robustbase")
mod.lm <- lm(log(Animals2$brain) ~ log(Animals2$body))
x <- rstudent(mod.lm)
gg_qq(x)
```

[image]

Comment: This is super helpful.  Have you thought about hosting your script on Github?  It would be nice to properly site your code,

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rentrop/d39a8406ad8af2a1066c like this? Even tho i dont know why you can't site SO...

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I suppose I misspoke slightly, what I meant it would be nice to have it posted on Github so can I bring it in as part of an R script (instead of finding a way to splice your Stack Overflow post.)

Answer (score 16):

Since version 3.0, a `stat_qq_line` equivalent to the below has [found its way into the official `ggplot2` code](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_qq.html).

---

**Old version**:

Since version 2.0, ggplot2 has a well-documented interface for extension; so we can now easily write a new stat for the qqline by itself (which I've done for the first time, so improvements are [welcome](https://gist.github.com/phipsgabler/91a81883a82a54bb6a92)):

```
qq.line <- function(data, qf, na.rm) {
    # from stackoverflow.com/a/4357932/1346276
    q.sample <- quantile(data, c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm)
    q.theory <- qf(c(0.25, 0.75))
    slope <- diff(q.sample) / diff(q.theory)
    intercept <- q.sample[1] - slope * q.theory[1]

    list(slope = slope, intercept = intercept)
}

StatQQLine <- ggproto("StatQQLine", Stat,
    # http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html
    # https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-qq.r
    
    required_aes = c('sample'),
    
    compute_group = function(data, scales,
                             distribution = stats::qnorm,
                             dparams = list(),
                             na.rm = FALSE) {
        qf <- function(p) do.call(distribution, c(list(p = p), dparams))
        
        n <- length(data$sample)
        theoretical <- qf(stats::ppoints(n))
        qq <- qq.line(data$sample, qf = qf, na.rm = na.rm)
        line <- qq$intercept + theoretical * qq$slope

        data.frame(x = theoretical, y = line)
    } 
)

stat_qqline <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "line",
                        position = "identity", ...,
                        distribution = stats::qnorm,
                        dparams = list(),
                        na.rm = FALSE,
                        show.legend = NA, 
                        inherit.aes = TRUE) {
    layer(stat = StatQQLine, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom,
          position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
          params = list(distribution = distribution,
                        dparams = dparams,
                        na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

This also generalizes over the distribution (exactly like `stat_qq` does), and can be used as follows:

```
> test.data <- data.frame(sample=rnorm(100, 10, 2)) # normal distribution
> test.data.2 <- data.frame(sample=rt(100, df=2))   # t distribution
> ggplot(test.data, aes(sample=sample)) + stat_qq() + stat_qqline()
> ggplot(test.data.2, aes(sample=sample)) + stat_qq(distribution=qt, dparams=list(df=2)) +
+   stat_qqline(distribution=qt, dparams=list(df=2))
```

(Unfortunately, since the qqline is on a separate layer, I couldn't find a way to "reuse" the distribution parameters, but that should only be a minor problem.)

Answer (score 14):

The standard Q-Q diagnostic for linear models plots quantiles of the **standardized** residuals vs. theoretical quantiles of N(0,1). @Peter's ggQQ function plots the residuals. The snippet below amends that and adds a few cosmetic changes to make the plot more like what one would get from `plot(lm(...))`.

```
ggQQ = function(lm) {
  # extract standardized residuals from the fit
  d <- data.frame(std.resid = rstandard(lm))
  # calculate 1Q/4Q line
  y <- quantile(d$std.resid[!is.na(d$std.resid)], c(0.25, 0.75))
  x <- qnorm(c(0.25, 0.75))
  slope <- diff(y)/diff(x)
  int <- y[1L] - slope * x[1L]

  p <- ggplot(data=d, aes(sample=std.resid)) +
    stat_qq(shape=1, size=3) +           # open circles
    labs(title="Normal Q-Q",             # plot title
         x="Theoretical Quantiles",      # x-axis label
         y="Standardized Residuals") +   # y-axis label
    geom_abline(slope = slope, intercept = int, linetype="dashed")  # dashed reference line
  return(p)
}
```

Example of use:

```
# sample data (y = x + N(0,1), x in [1,100])
df <- data.frame(cbind(x=c(1:100),y=c(1:100+rnorm(100))))
ggQQ(lm(y~x,data=df))
```

Answer (score 10):

With the latest ggplot2 version (>=3.0), new function `stat_qq_line` is implemented (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md) and a qq line for model residuals can be added with:

```
library(ggplot2)
model <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)
ggplot(model, aes(sample = rstandard(model))) + geom_qq() + stat_qq_line()
```

`rstandard(model)` is needed to get the standardized residual. (credit @jlhoward and @qwr)

If you get an 'Error in stat_qq_line() : could not find function "stat_qq_line"', your ggplot2 version is too old and you can fix it by upgrading your ggplot2 package: `install.packages("ggplot2")` .

Comment: This is now released in stable version ggplot2 3.0.0. So you can now get this feature from the CRAN version.

Comment: Ggplot expects **standardized** residuals as jlhoward describes. So use `rstandard(model)` instead of `.resid`

Answer (score 9):

Why not the following?

Given some vector, say,

```
myresiduals <- rnorm(100) ^ 2

ggplot(data=as.data.frame(qqnorm( myresiduals , plot=F)), mapping=aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

But it seems strange that we have to use a traditional graphics function to prop up ggplot2.

Can't we get the same effect somehow by starting with the vector for which we want the quantile plot and then applying the appropriate "stat" and "geom" functions in ggplot2?

Does Hadley Wickham monitor these posts? Maybe he can show us a better way.

Comment: the scatter plot resembles the q-q plot of the qqnorm() but the line added by geom_smooth is not same as the one given by qqline(). The solutions given by Aaron and @jlhoward, on the other hand , give plots similar to the base R ones. Can you comment if it is my data, because of which it is misbehaving.

Answer (score 4):

You could steal a page from the old-timers who did this stuff with normal probability paper.  A careful look at a ggplot()+stat_qq() graphic suggests that a reference line can be added with geom_abline(), like this

```
df <- data.frame( y=rpois(100, 4) )

ggplot(df, aes(sample=y)) +
  stat_qq() +
  geom_abline(intercept=mean(df$y), slope = sd(df$y))
```

Comment: Shouldn't a Q-Q plot with sample vs theoretical quantiles have reference line y=x?

Answer (score 1):

ggplot2 v.3.0.0 now has an qqline stat. From the help page:

```
df <- data.frame(y = rt(200, df = 5))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(sample = y))
p + stat_qq() + stat_qq_line()
```

[!ggplot2 v3.0.0 Example stats equivalent to qqnorm plus abline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmKny.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmKny.png)