# plotting two samples against the uniform distribution in R

Tags: r, plot

I am very much an R novice so I am guessing this question is rather stupid/simple...

I have two vectors that represent two samples.
I would like to plot each of them (different colors) against the uniform CDF (something like a Q-Q plot).

To be precise, I would like something very similar to plot #7 [here](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/advanced_graphs/q-q_plots.html) (could not find what was used to draw that plot...). Figure 7 is displayed below:

[image]

only with multiple samples and some flexibility with changing the axis labels, colors and such.

Could you please point at a good direction?

Comment: A good starting point could be reading [`?qqplot`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/qqnorm.html).

Comment: I once [tried to do something similar with `ggplot`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599745/qqline-in-ggplot2-with-facets/19600903#19600903).

Comment: Thank you both. I chose to use ggplot + stat_qq. I now struggle with tinier problems :-\  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499216/changing-line-width-in-stat-qq-with-ggplot-in-r

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
set.seed(10)
N <- 1000
B = rt(N,df=10)
C = rchisq(N,df=10)
op <- layout(matrix(c(1,2),ncol=2,nrow=1))
qqnorm(B,col='green',ylab='student')
qqline(B, col = 2)
qqnorm(C,col='blue',ylab=expression( chi^2 ))
qqline(C, col = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basics for drawing a QQ-plot are:

```
qqnorm(variable, main = "QQ Plot", xlab = "Theoretical Quantiles", ylab = "Sample Quantiles")
qqline(variable, col = "red")
```