# qqnorm plotting for multiple subsets

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I have figured out how to make `qqnorm` plots on a subset of my dataframe. However, I would like to make `qqnorm` plots on subsets that are defined by two factors (one factor has 48 categories (brain_region) and each of those categories can be further subdivided by another factor, which has three levels (GroupID)). I have tried the following:

```
by(t, t[,"GroupID"], function(x) tapply(t$FA,t$brain_region,qqnorm))
```

but it does not seem to be working. I'm also not sure if this is the best approach, as I'm new to this program.

I would also like to save each of the separately generated `qqnorm` plot with the x axis as labeled as "FA" and the title with the specific level of each of the two factors (brain region/GroupID). Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599745/qqline-in-ggplot2-with-facets/19600903#19600903) may be a start. For next time, please note that people are generally much more happy to help if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) together with the code you have tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotting is one of the few things where `apply` isn't the optimal solution. `ggplot` offers you enough possibilities to get this done, as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599745/qqline-in-ggplot2-with-facets/19600903#19600903).

**Plotting all levels in one go**

If you use the base plots, you can better use a `for` loop for this. Plus, if you want to plot different plots on the same graphics device, you can use eg `par(mfrow=)` or `layout` (see the help page `?layout`)

Let's take the built-in data set `iris` as an example:

```
data(iris)

op <- par(mfrow=c(1,3))
for(i in levels(iris$Species)){
  tmp <- with(iris, Petal.Width[Species==i])
  qqnorm(tmp,xlab="Petal.Width",main=i)
  qqline(tmp)
}
par(op)
rm(i,tmp)
```

gives :

[image]

Don't forget to clean up your workspace after using a `for` loop. Not really obligatory, but it can prevent serious confusion later on.

**Combine two factors**

In order to get this done for 2 factor levels at the same time, you can either construct a nested `for`-loop, or combine both factors into a single factor. Take the dataset mtcars:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am,
                    labels=c('automatic','manual'))
```

To combine both levels, you can use this simple construct :

```
mtcars$combined <- factor(paste(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$am,sep='/'))
```

And then do the same again. With two `for` loops, your code would like like the code below. Be warned though that this only works if you have data for every combination of the factors, and you don't have too many levels. If you have a lot of levels, you better save the plots by using eg `png()` (see `?png` for info) instead of plotting them all on the same graphics device.

```
lcyl <- levels(mtcars$cyl)
lam <- levels(mtcars$am)

par(mfrow=c(length(lam),length(lcyl)))

for(i in lam){
  for(j in lcyl){
    tmp <- with(mtcars,mpg[am==i & cyl==j])
    qqnorm(tmp,xlab="Petal.Width",
           main=paste(i,j,sep="/"))
    qqline(tmp)    
  }
}
```

gives :

[image]