# Pairs matrix with qq-plots

Tags: r

It is helpful to be able to view your data.  When you have several variables, you can form a scatterplot matrix with, for example, `pairs()`.  A scatterplot matrix gives you a set of 2D marginal projections of your data.

```
set.seed(8092)
X <- matrix(rnorm(80), ncol=4)
pairs(X)
```

[image]

You can also have data for different groups and want to compare their distributions.  Two such distributions can be compared with a qq-plot.

```
set.seed(4415)
group1 <- rnorm(20)
group2 <- rnorm(20)
qqplot(group1, group2)
abline(c(0,1))
```

[image]

When you have several groups, it would be convenient if there were a pairs-type plot that would display a matrix of qq-plots.

```
colnames(X) <- c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4")
qq.pairs(X)
```

Is there such a function?  Is there a straightforward way to code it from scratch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599745/qqline-in-ggplot2-with-facets

Comment: As a general remark, I would highly recommend `ggplot2`. It is awesome.

Comment: Thanks for the link @NPE. I'm not sure if I follow the code in the answer there. Is it plotting 1 set of empirical data against another set of empirical data, or empirical data against a theoretical normal? It seems to be the latter.

Comment: That link was meant as a pointer for further research, not as a complete solution to your exact problem. The code in that question can, however, be easily adapted to your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add whatever function you like via the `*panel` args. For example:

```
set.seed(8092)
X <- matrix(rnorm(80), ncol=4)

panel.qq <- function(x, y, ...) {
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1), new = TRUE)
  qqplot(x, y, xlab = deparse(substitute(x)), ylab = deparse(substitute(y)))
  abline(c(0,1), ...)
}

pairs(X, lower.panel = panel.qq)
```

[image]

Of course you can use `panel=panel.qq` to make all the squares qq plots

Comment: That's great, thanks. I thought there was a way to do it. I skimmed the `pairs` documentation, but I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

I got an error with just putting `qqplot` in the panel function which it appears @rawr solved by using 'new=TRUE'. My approach was to pull out the x and y values and use `points`:

```
panel.qq <- function(x,y, ...)
{    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(usr[1:2], -2,2) )
    QQ <- qqplot(x,y, plot.it = FALSE)
    x <- QQ$x; 
    y <- QQ$y; 
    points(x, y, col = "cyan", ...)
    abline(0,1)
}

set.seed(8092)
X <- matrix(rnorm(80), ncol=4)
pairs(X, upper.panel=panel.qq)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's nice to have a couple different ways to do it.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Your high level of statistical advice over on CV is also appreciated.

Comment: *& my low level of programming ability (sigh)...*

Comment: I think it is easier to address the programming part than the statistical part.