# Computing a correlation matrix with both numerical and logical variables

Tags: r, correlation

I need to create a correlation matrix for my dataframe that contains both numerical and logical (binary) variables. Is it possible to do it in R? Do you have any suggestions?

Example:

```
a <- (data.frame(a=c(34,54,55,12,13,6), b=factor(c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE), 0:1), C=c(1:6)))
```

Thanks

Comment: In my case something like `cor(data.frame(a=1:3, b=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)))` works.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know :)

Comment: Look at the latentcor package.

Comment: I tried with the cor command, but it gives me the error "x must be numeric"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether your question is about the creation of a `data.frame` object with several types of variables (see comment) or how to compute correlations if your data is, as you mentioned, "numerical and binary" (*). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554336/plot-the-equivalent-of-correlation-matrix-for-factors-categorical-data-and-mi) might help. I assume in particular Dan Chaltiel's answer (last answer) will help you.

(*) In the letter case the thread is possibly a duplicate.

---

***EDIT:*** Considering Dan Chaltiel's approach (see link), does this help?

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(34,54,55,12,13,6), 
                 b=c("FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"), 
                 c=c(1:6))

library(dplyr)

model.matrix(~0+., data=df) %>% 
  cor(use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Comment: Yes, i refer to the second case you mentioned. Sorry for the lack of accuracy in asking, i'm a newbie :)

Comment: Does the link help?

Comment: I tried with the cor command, but it gives me the error "x must be numeric"

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide data and code (see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Comment: I edited my post, I just made use of things the link provides.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot... Though I didn't understand why. I clearly do not master the subject, i will try to read better the link you provided! THANKS :)