# How to make a correlation matrix of categorical variables showing only frequency of both variables as 1

Tags: r, plot, statistics, correlation

I have a dataframe with papers and the parameters they reported one-hot encoded:
[image: screenshot of table on R].

```
structure(list(CitationKey = c("White2021", "Tunabot2019", "Fujiwara2017", 
"Dewar1994a", "Dewar1994b", "Blank2007_BF", "Blank2007_YF", "Katzschmann2018", 
"Leftwich2012", "Gibouin2018", "Donley2000_KT", "Donley2000_CM", 
"Sepulveda2000_KT", "Sepulveda2000_CM", "Sepulveda2000_YF", "Salumae2013", 
"Jezov2012", "Anderson2000", "ShaoXu2019", "Rufo2013", "LauderFlammangAlben2012", 
"Low2010", "Chong2009", "Niu2014", "LiuHu2005", "LiuHu2010", 
"Tan2006", "Zhang2010", "Zhong2018a", "Zhong2018b", "ZhongDu2016", 
"Xie2020", "Struebig2020", "Bainbridge1958_CD", "Bainbridge1958_T", 
"Bainbridge1958_G", "Videler1991_PV", "Videler1991_TS", "Videler1991_AF", 
"Videler1991_SScom", "Videler1991_GM", "Videler1991_TT", "Videler1991_OM"
), COM = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Duty_Cycle = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Re ` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Flow_Speed = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), Drag_Force = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Drag_Coefficient = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Head_Amplitude = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), Tail_Amplitude = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Frequency = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), COT = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Stride_Length = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), Swimming_Speed = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Strouhal_Number = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WPM = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), Thrust = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Energy_Consumption = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Acceleration = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), Wavelength = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Turning_Speed = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Turning_Radius = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), Lateral_Force = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Power = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Efficiency = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Turning_Diameter = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Yaw Rate` = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), Voltage = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Turning_Angle = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), Froude_Efficiency = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Speed_Efficiency = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -43L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554336/plot-the-equivalent-of-correlation-matrix-for-factors-categorical-data-and-mi), I was able to make a correlation matrix

```
reduced_df[,2:ncol(reduced_df)] %>% 
  cor(use="pairwise.complete.obs", method='spearman') %>% 
  ggcorrplot(show.diag = F, 
             type="lower", 
             lab=TRUE, 
             lab_size=2)
```

[image: correlation matrix]

However, COM and Duty_Cycle, for example have a value of 1.0 because they are both present in the same paper once, and then neither are reported in any other papers - so they correlate exactly. Frequency and COT, however, are co-reported in 8 papers and then vary, so they don't correlate well. I'd like to alter the correlation matrix to show the frequency of both parameters being co-reported in the same papers. COT and Frequency should be 8x higher in value than COM and Duty Cycle.

However, I don't know how to do this. I'd greatly appreciate any advice or ideas.

Comment: If you could create a reproducible example and not a screenshot of your data that would be great.

Comment: Of course! I added a link in the original post to a github repo with a csv of the dataframe. Does that work?

Comment: I think it's general practice to not add links to pictures and outside websites unless it's specifically to add context to an answer as it can lead to malware, etc. If you could use `dput()` on your dataset in your console and paste that in your question I think you'll get a response much faster.

Comment: Interesting. Like so?

Comment: Yes! Very helpful