# What does the ~0+. object mean in R?

Tags: r

I came across [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554336/plot-the-equivalent-of-correlation-matrix-for-factors-categorical-data-and-mi/61482149#61482149) for [how to map non factorial data into a correlation matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554336/plot-the-equivalent-of-correlation-matrix-for-factors-categorical-data-and-mi) in which the solution uses an argument `~0+.`. For reference, here's the code:

> ```r
> library(ggcorrplot)
> model.matrix(~0+., data=df) %>% 
>  cor(use="pairwise.complete.obs") %>% 
>  ggcorrplot(show.diag = F, type="lower", lab=TRUE, lab_size=2)
> ```

What does the object `~0+.` do in this scenario?

I tried looking up the meaning of the operator `~` and tried to make sense of the formula, but I cannot understand how it this formula helping us create a mapping of factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a formula object (see `help("formula")`for details).

`.` means all variables (columns), `0` means exclude the intercept.

You pass the formula to `model.matrix`, which creates a [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix). It does automatic dummy encoding of factor variables (using treatment contrasts by default). Excluding the intercept ensures there is a column for each factor level in the design matrix.