# Q-Q plot facet wrap with QQ line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, facet

How do I produce a facet wrap of qqnorm showing qqlines for some data?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599745/qqline-in-ggplot2-with-facets/19600903#19600903) produces the qqplot but is not plotting a true qqline on the plot (only a smoothed lm of the data).  Code is copied from linked question.

```
library(plyr)

# create some data
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(vals = rnorm(1000, 10),
                  y = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 1000, replace = TRUE),
                  z = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, replace = TRUE))

# calculate the normal theoretical quantiles per group
df2 <- ddply(.data = df1, .variables = .(y, z), function(dat){
             q <- qqnorm(dat$vals, plot = FALSE)
             dat$xq <- q$x
             dat
}
)

# plot the sample values against the theoretical quantiles
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = xq, y = vals)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  xlab("Theoretical") +
  ylab("Sample") +
  facet_grid(y ~ z)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any need for `plyr` or calling `qqnorm` youself. YOu can just do

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(sample=vals)) +
  geom_qq() + 
  geom_qq_line(color="red") + 
  xlab("Theoretical") +
  ylab("Sample") +
  facet_grid(y ~ z)
```

[image]