# qqplot against theoretical quantiles

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I want to be able to do qqplots against theoretical quantiles. I already know `qqnorm()` does that for the normal distribution, but that's a pretty a limited tool to me. Also, I noticed that some people simulate random processes from a given distribution and use it to compare to sample data, which is not entirely rigorous because it depends on the method of simulation. So my example would be to compare sample data to geometric distribution:

```
#sample data
var=rgeom(prob=0.3, n=100)

#QQplot against a theoretical geometric distribution with prob=0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce such a plot easily with the `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(sample = var, geom = "point", stat = "qq", 
      distribution = qgeom, dparams = list(prob = 0.5))
```

The theoretical quantiles (x axis) are derived from a geometric distribution with a probability of 0.5.
[image]

*Update* (based on question in comment):

A line can be added in the following way though it is not very well suited for geometric distribution. The approach is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357932/1627235).

```
qv <- quantile(var, c(.25, .75))
qt <- qgeom(prob = 0.5, c(.25, .75))
slope <- diff(qv)/diff(qt)
int <- qv[1] - slope * qt[1]

qplot(sample = var, geom = "point", stat = "qq", 
      distribution = qgeom, dparams = list(prob = 0.5)) + 
  geom_abline(slope = slope, intercept = int)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, how do I add that classical bisection line?

Comment: @user3083324 This line doesn't make much sense for your distributions.  However, have a look at the update.

Comment: OP's `var` is taken from `rgeom(...)` with prob=0.3, your plots have prob=0.5.

Comment: @jlhoward Have a look at the question (in particular the last line).

Comment: As u lower the theoretical prob parameter the closer the line gets to the points.

Comment: @user3083324 This behaviour is not surprising. Since your random data are based on a probability of 0.3, you will get the closest match between both distributions when the theoretical quantiles are based on a probability of 0.3 too.

Comment: I know! I was answering ur previous point about the tail of the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

A Q-Q plot is a plot of quantiles of a ramdom sample against quantiles of the test distribution. So,

```
plot(qgeom(seq(0,1,length=100),.3),quantile(var,seq(0,1,length=100)))
```

[image]