# Standardized residuals x Theoretical Quantiles plot in ggplot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a plot "Theoretical Quantiles"X "Standardized Residuals" using `ggplot2` package.

I have a `lm()` model that I used to this plot

```
library(ggplot2)

model<-lm(mpg~cyl+disp+hp+drat+wt, data=mtcars)

p2<-ggplot(model, aes(qqnorm(.stdresid)[[1]], .stdresid))+geom_point(na.rm = TRUE)
p2<-p2+geom_abline(aes(qqline(.stdresid)))+xlab("Theoretical Quantiles")+ylab("Standardized Residuals")
p2<-p2+ggtitle("Normal Q-Q")+theme_bw()
p2
```

This code that I founded here https://rpubs.com/therimalaya/43190 make the plot, but returns an error

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3110): x
```

and I can't change the `xlab` or `ylab` names. How I can solve it?

Comment: Could you please make this reproducible?

Comment: @Hack-R How I do it?

Comment: Provide the necessary code and data within the question to reproduce the problem. I know you provided a link but they want it within the question and even using the link it's a little unclear as you have to hunt for where you're taking the code from within another function, find the corresponding model and rename the object, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  I went ahead and fixed it for you this time.

Comment: This is _really_ close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357031/qqnorm-and-qqline-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model<-lm(mpg~cyl+disp+hp+drat+wt, data=mtcars)

library(ggplot2)

p2 <- ggplot(model, aes(qqnorm(.stdresid)[[1]], .stdresid))+geom_point(na.rm = TRUE)
p2 <- p2+geom_abline()+xlab("Theoretical Quantiles")+ylab("Standardized Residuals")
p2 <- p2+ggtitle("Normal Q-Q")+theme_bw()
p2
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, you know what is the problem in abline function?

Comment: @Roland Happy to help. The `aes` argument was not the appropriate length and was apparently totally unncessary. It was a mistake in the example, probably because they were copying from the earlier line which contained an `aes` call and only partially deleted the argument. I'd recommend to email the author so that they can fix their example, though it is 2 years old at this point.